# Can I use uninsulated ducts and boots for a short circular run through a humidifier?

Tags: hvac, insulation

I have a boiler room with outside air inlet so it can get cold/hot in the room, standard drywall stud wall between basement and boiler room. I’m going to install an aprilaire 300 evaporative humidifier with registers into the boiler room as in the below pic. Can I use uninsulated ducts and boots for this short run?

[image: aprilaire instructions]

Comment: I don't think I am best qualified to answer, but that is one great drawing.

Comment: is there some reason why you don't want to install the humidifier in the boiler room?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes it's likely fine to use uninsulated materials for your project.

Usually it makes sense to run a humidifier only during heating season (adding humidity during cooling season would make the cooling less efficient). So, during heating season, is the boiler room warmer than the basement space? If so then uninsulated ducts will help you gain more heat into the basement! On the other hand, if the boiler room is cooler than the basement during this part of the year, the uninsulated ducts could increase heat loss. But are those partition walls insulated? Is the door well-sealed? A little bit more heat loss may or may not be significant in the grand scheme.

What about cooling season? The humidifier would not run during this part of the year. If by some miracle the boiler room were cooler than the basement you might get a bit of free cooling. In the more likely event that the boiler room is warmer than the basement during cooling season, then yes you could experience some unwanted heat gain from the boiler room into the basement. But again, if the boiler room is not already particularly well-sealed against heat transfer to the basement, the extra heat to be gained through the humidifier duct work just may not be significant enough to warrant the expense and trouble of installing insulated boots and duct.